# Connecting buck converter to 10mF 40v filter capacitor

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, buck-boost

I have a very well made custom-made lab supply given to me by a friend. It is capable of `1.6A` max and `32V DC` voltage.

I want to add a secondary output to this supply but I have a hard time figuring what point in the system I should choose as input to [this](https://www.ebay.com/itm/2-5-10-PCS-Boost-Buck-DC-adjustable-step-up-down-Converter-XL6009-Module-Voltage/182804193348?pageci=70e745bb-7fe3-4767-aa27-d9da450efd70) buck-boost module.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fs58iY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- `C1` capacitor has `32V` across it.
- The `Variable Switched Supply` look like [this converter](https://www.hellasdigital.gr/electronics/boost-and-buck-converters/dc-dc-8a-automatic-step-up-step-down-adjustable-power-module/?sl=en) or something similar. This module is actually controlled by a voltage pot and a current limit one.

I experienced the full power of the cap when I tried to rush the discharge with a screwdriver.
This makes me wander:

**Q1:** *If I were to add the buck converter directly to this cap would it be sufficiently safe? Could I get electrocuted if there was a direct path from the cap to me?*

Currently the buck-boost is connected to `OUT1` and `OUT2` DC outputs which I consider safe (the module I added is capable of step up and step down transforming). The problem with this configuration is that at about `3.5V` on the standard output the  module triggers the short circuit protection and never recovers. I have to cut the power, wait a few seconds and only then does the output voltage recover.

**Q2:** *Why is the module shortcircuiting? I presume the IC has some undervoltage protection. Is this normal behaviour?*

Comment: Schematic please! Is your 40 V cap isolated from the mains? What’s the voltage rating on the buck?

Comment: The output seems to be isolated. The supply has a big transformer inside and I couldn't see a connection between primary ans secondary. I am sorry about the schematic but I will have to add it later. In my timezone is already midnight.

Comment: I was just wondering if the 32V from an capacitor could kill me. Note that all the circuuts pass by a 6.3A and then 1.25A fuses

Comment: Highly unlikely. What’s the input voltage rating for the buck?

Comment: The rating for the buck that I want to add is 3.8V-32V. What I find weird is that lowering this voltage to 3.5V seems to make the module short circuit.

Comment: You need to pay attention to the specifications. The buck has 30 V input max. If you supplied it with 32 V, expect it to break. The capacitor voltage rating is irrelevant as long as you are below that value.

Comment: I think you 'switched' them. I will clarify the question. My supply has a transformer inside and then the filtered 32 V go into the "automatic step step down transformer"(the second link). This is how I got the unit and it worked perfectly. It is possible the unit I linked is not exactly to mine but it has the same as appeareance. The buck I want to add wbich is the one from ebay has 32V input range

Comment: The ebay description is typical for chineese. It references two input voltage ranges but I think the correct one is the 3.8-32V one

Comment: Please draw a schematic and/or block diagram. It's far better than words.

Comment: I added the schematic. As you can see the basic question remains: Can 32V electrocute me if the buck module fails?

Comment: Much better! No electrocution. What's your measured unloaded DC voltage at C1?

Comment: Well...32V. Unloaded meaning nothing attached to the OUT1 and OUT2 (but with the switched power supply in power) I assume. So right now I could stick my fingers on that cap and nothing would happen?

Comment: Assuming your circuit is exaclty like what you described. If your transformer is actually an autotransformer, isolation has failed or anything similar, you'll die from electrocution. 32 V is too high for your buck module. Get one with higher input voltage rating.

Comment: Why will failure of isolation electrocute me? Isn't it the same voltage aka 32V across the cap leads as it would be if the voltage was referenced to the primary (and probably the case)?

Comment: No, you will also be part of the circuit between 220 Vac and ground at the same time. 32 Vdc will not kill you. 220 Vac will.I'll try to dig up a picture for you.

Comment: I still don't understand the 220 to ground path. The case is grounded and the cap has only 32V. Even if any of the 4 terminal wires were referenced to earth I still couldn't touch the live wires. Could you explain more?

Comment: You are asking me if you can bet your life on something and I'm telling you there are specific cases where you can't. Your transformer being an autotransformer is one of them. The true transformer having any isolation problem, is not wired as shown in your schematic or any variation here is another. If you have a multimeter capable of measureing AC voltage (and preferably current), you can rule such cases out. Non the less, you should not bet your life on it.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: Your cap is seperated from main line, so voltages below 48V are no problem to touch. The resistance of your body is too high to let the current flow.

Don't know, what the buck-converter does. If any charge would increase voltage of your whole circiut relative to earth over 48V, then, to be a littly bit more safe, you could connect your secondary GND to Earth.

Comment: It seems the cheap buck converter uses the mighty "XL6009 " which has no undervoltage protection. It seems to be very unstable under 3V. https://owenduffy.net/blog/?p=12435